# Use python to process word files

Tags: python, python-3.x, ms-word, ms-office, python-docx

I have a 1000 word files (`A1, ..., A1000`).

I look forward to creating code, to do:

- Copy all the contents and formatting inside the A1 file to a word file named B
- Save it to a folder `Change` with a name of `A1`

The same goes for the A2, ..., A1000 files. Constant word file B.

Looking forward to everyone's help

**Note**: when copying, the format must remain the same (bold, italic,..) and in file A there are pictures, tables, drawings ,...

I've tried using the docx library but haven't been able to do it yet

I wish to use Python for this process.

Comment: What code exactly have you tried so far?